# Store data in HBASE without specifying schema

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to store data in **HBASE** using pig but all the examples i found require schema creation in **Pig**. Without creating schema how can i achieve this as my data can have variable number of fields. Need help.

**EDIT:**

I have HL7 data which is in below format

```
MSH|^~\&|Roqua|RGOc|||20121120113522||ORU^R01|8da2b665b7|P|2.4|||||||
PID|1||123^^^^^^^|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
OBR|1||2599||||201211201139||||||||mansa||||||||||S
OBX|1|ST|mansa_protocol^MANSA Protocol^L||ROM||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|2|ST|mansa_project^MANSA Project^L||Meettraject 1||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|3|ST|mansa_measurement^MANSA Measurement^L||Evaluatie||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|4|ST|mansa_notes^MANSA Notes^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|5|ST|mansa_location^MANSA Location^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|6|ST|mansa_compl_by^MANSA Completed By^L||123||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|7|NM|mansa_totaal^MANSA Score^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|8|ST|mansa_1^MANSA v_1^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|9|ST|mansa_6^MANSA v_6^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|10|ST|mansa_7^MANSA v_7^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|11|ST|mansa_8^MANSA v_8^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|12|ST|mansa_9^MANSA v_9^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|13|ST|mansa_10^MANSA v_10^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|14|ST|mansa_11^MANSA v_11^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|15|ST|mansa_12^MANSA v_12^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|16|ST|mansa_13^MANSA v_13^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|17|ST|mansa_14^MANSA v_14^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|18|ST|mansa_15^MANSA v_15^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|19|ST|mansa_16^MANSA v_16^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|20|ST|mansa_17^MANSA v_17^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|21|ST|mansa_18^MANSA v_18^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|22|ST|mansa_19^MANSA v_19^L||||||||S|||201211201139
OBX|23|ST|mansa_20^MANSA v_20^L||||||||S|||201211201139
```

I don't know how to store this in HBASE as there can be multiple MSH, OBR and OBX in single HL7 file.

Comment: In general I believe the anwer to be `you can't`. Pig is strict in this way. However, if you could describe your situation there may be a workaround.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin i have updated my question please check.